# Integrate google-cloud with firebase functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

When integrating google cloud on node.js, as described here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-cloud

One should include a json file with the secret credentials and keys:

```
var config = {

projectId: 'grape-spaceship-123',

keyFilename: '/path/to/keyfile.json'

};
```

When using firebase functions / google cloud functions, how can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Functions run as a trusted cloud account already. In most cases you shouldn't need to add a credentials JSON file. For example, this is [how we initialize Cloud Storage in one of our apps](https://github.com/mimming/zero-to-app-emojistories/blob/master/functions/index.js#L22):

```
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
```

As you see, we're not passing in any authorization information, yet the code is still able to access Cloud Storage:

```
const file = gcs.bucket('YOUR_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com').file(filePath);
```

---

If you have a case where you need the credentials file:

1. [Download the JSON file with the credentials](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk).
2. Put the JSON file into your `functions directory.
3. Refer to it from your code: `keyFilename: './keyfile.json'`